# print each 10 numbers in line always printing the first value alone

Tags: python

I have this loop which print each 10 numbers in line then move to next line

```
   for i in range(100, 201):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(i)

        else:
            print(i, end=" ", )
```

and this the result:

```
100
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130
131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140
141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160
161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170
171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190
191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
```

it printing first number in line alone, but the want the opposite, the last number alone, something like this

```
 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129
 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139
 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149
 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159
 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169
 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179
 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189
 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
 200
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want? First value alone or last value alone?

Comment: `if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:`

Comment: @kaziAbid last value alone check last example in the end of question how the result should looks like

Comment: @IainShelvington like this it is printing all values in one line

Comment: make this `if i % 10 == 9` so you will always print the line ending with 9 and then go to next line

Comment: @JoeFerndz dude thanks so much it works

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct code. The only thing is that you are breaking at mod 0. You should break at mod 9.

```
for i in range(100, 201):
        if i % 10 == 9:
            print(i)

        else:
            print(i, end=" ", )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in range(100, 201):
    if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
        print(i)

    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, 100 % 10 is equals to zero.
Which means it's going to print 100 in a line, and 101 in another line.
If you want the new line to start from 100 then all you have to do is to make the statement `i % 10 == 0` a false statement. So you will have to add one to the 100.
so just try this code instead

```
for i in range(100, 201):
    if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(i)

    else:
        print(i, end=" ", )
```

or you could try changing `i % 10 == 0` to `i % 10 == 9`

Answer (score 0):

What I Can Say By Seeing Your Code Is That You Are Using 2 Print Statements. One Inside The If Statement And One Inside Else Statement.

So What Python Compiler Is Doing There Is Printing New Line When Each If Statement Is True.

So When Your Iterating Number%10 Will Be Zero It Will Print That Number And Add A New Line, Because After Each Print Statement Python Do So.

And As You Have end=" " in Else Statement So It Is Printing The Number In Same Line When IF Statements Are False.

So What You Can Do Is:

You Can Use if (i+1)%10: instead of i % 10 == 0:

When Your Iterating Number's(i's) One's Place Will Be 9 (i.e. 109,119,etc) The If Statement Will Be True For That One, The Number Will Be Printed On The Same Line And Will Add A New Line After That.